# Reading and writing persistent data on Pebble

Tags: integer, persistent, cloudpebble

I am making a very simple archery field score tracking app for Pebble and I am having issues with storing and retrieving integer values between sessions. The act of storing and retrieving is working fine, but for some odd reason only 1 value is retrieved and then populated in to the second variable so they are both the same.

Pasting my full code, including my debug logging while trying to figure it out. All values are correct even when unloading the window, but when retrieving the values on the next window load, it seems to just get 1... ?

```
/*  TODO
    - Show time bar along top of screen
*/

#include <pebble.h>

uint32_t keyTotal,keyTargets;
static Window *window;
static TextLayer *text_layer_SCORE,*text_layer_TARGETS,*text_layer_TOTAL,*text_layer_TITLE;
int score,targets,total;
char targetText[]="Targets: ";
char scoreText[]="Score: ";
char totalText[]="TOTAL: ";
char currentScore[]="Score: xxxx";
char currentTotal[]="TOTAL: xxxx";
char currentTargets[]="Targets: xxx";

static void logValues(char *string) {
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, string);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- SCORE: %i", score);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- TOTAL: %i", total);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- TARGETS: %i", targets);
}

static void updateScore() {
  snprintf(currentScore,sizeof(currentScore),"%s %d",scoreText,score);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_SCORE, currentScore);

  logValues("----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE");
}

static void updateTotal() {
  snprintf(currentTotal,sizeof(currentTotal),"%s %d",totalText,total);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_TOTAL, currentTotal);

  logValues("----- UPDATE TOTAL");
}

static void updateTargets() {
  snprintf(currentTargets,sizeof(currentTargets),"%s %d",targetText,targets);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_TARGETS, currentTargets);

  logValues("----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS");
}

static void updateAll() {
  updateTotal();
  updateTargets();
  updateScore();

  logValues("----- AFTER UPDATE ALL");
}

static void persistValues() {
  persist_write_int(keyTotal, total);
  persist_write_int(keyTargets, targets);

  logValues("----- AFTER PERSIST VALUES");
}

static void resetValues() {
  score = 0;
  total = 0;
  targets = 0;
  persist_write_int(keyTargets, 0);
  persist_write_int(keyTotal, 0);

  logValues("----- AFTER RESET VALUES");
}

static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  total = total + score;
  ++targets;
  updateAll();

  logValues("----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED");
}

static void up_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  // text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Up");
  score++;
  updateScore();

  logValues("----- AFTER UP PRESSED");
}

static void down_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  // text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Down");
  score--;
  updateScore();

  logValues("----- AFTER DOWN PRESSED");
}

static void up_long_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  //Window *window = (Window *)context;
}

static void up_long_click_release_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  //Window *window = (Window *)
  resetValues();
  updateAll();
}

static void click_config_provider(void *context) {
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, select_click_handler);
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, up_click_handler);
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_DOWN, down_click_handler);
  window_long_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, 3000, up_long_click_handler, up_long_click_release_handler);
}

static void window_load(Window *window) {
  Layer *window_layer = window_get_root_layer(window);
  GRect bounds = layer_get_bounds(window_layer);

  logValues("----- START OF WINDOW LOAD");

  score = 0;

  // Get previous total (if it exists)
  if(persist_exists(keyTotal)) {
    total = persist_read_int(keyTotal);
  } else {
    total = 0;
    //persist_write_int(keyTotal, total);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- PERSIST TOTAL NOT FOUND, SETTING: %i", total);
  }

  // Get previous targets (if it exists)
  if(persist_exists(keyTargets)) {
    targets = persist_read_int(keyTargets);
  } else {
    targets = 0;
    //persist_write_int(keyTargets, targets);
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- PERSIST TARGETS NOT FOUND, SETTING: %i", targets);
  }

  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- PERSIST END, TOTAL IS CURRENTLY: %i", total);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "----- PERSIST END, TOTAL IS CURRENTLY: %i", total);

  window_set_click_config_provider(window, (ClickConfigProvider) click_config_provider);

  text_layer_TITLE = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, bounds.size.w, bounds.size.h));
  text_layer_SCORE = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 40, bounds.size.w, 35));
  text_layer_TARGETS = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 80, bounds.size.w, 35));
  text_layer_TOTAL = text_layer_create(GRect(0,120, bounds.size.w, 50));

  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_TITLE, "ScoreTracker");

  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_SCORE, currentScore);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_TARGETS, currentTargets);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer_TOTAL, currentTotal);

  updateAll();

  text_layer_set_text_color(text_layer_TOTAL, GColorWhite);
  text_layer_set_text_color(text_layer_TARGETS, GColorWhite);
  text_layer_set_text_color(text_layer_SCORE, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_background_color(text_layer_TITLE, GColorGreen);
  text_layer_set_background_color(text_layer_TOTAL, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_background_color(text_layer_SCORE, GColorLightGray);
  text_layer_set_background_color(text_layer_TARGETS, GColorBlue);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(text_layer_TITLE, GTextAlignmentCenter);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(text_layer_SCORE, GTextAlignmentLeft);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(text_layer_TARGETS, GTextAlignmentLeft);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(text_layer_TOTAL, GTextAlignmentCenter);

  // Fonts
  text_layer_set_font(text_layer_TITLE, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_28_BOLD));
  text_layer_set_font(text_layer_SCORE, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_24_BOLD));
  text_layer_set_font(text_layer_TARGETS, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_24_BOLD));
  text_layer_set_font(text_layer_TOTAL, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_28_BOLD));

  layer_add_child(window_layer, text_layer_get_layer(text_layer_TITLE));
  layer_add_child(window_layer, text_layer_get_layer(text_layer_SCORE));
  layer_add_child(window_layer, text_layer_get_layer(text_layer_TARGETS));
  layer_add_child(window_layer, text_layer_get_layer(text_layer_TOTAL));

  logValues("----- END OF WINDOW LOAD");
}

static void window_unload(Window *window) {
  text_layer_destroy(text_layer_SCORE);
  text_layer_destroy(text_layer_TARGETS);
  text_layer_destroy(text_layer_TOTAL);
  text_layer_destroy(text_layer_TITLE);
  persistValues();

  logValues("----- END OF WINDOW UNLOAD");
}

static void init(void) {
  window = window_create();
  window_set_click_config_provider(window, click_config_provider);

  window_set_window_handlers(window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = window_load,
    .unload = window_unload,
  });
  const bool animated = true;
  window_stack_push(window, animated);

  logValues("----- END OF INIT");
}

static void deinit(void) {
  window_destroy(window);
}

int main(void) {
  init();

  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Done initializing, pushed window: %p", window);

  app_event_loop();
  deinit();
}
```

Here is the log output from running the above app code, making some score changes, exiting and reloading the app.

```
[INFO] ocess_manager.c:419: Heap Usage for App <ScoreTrack: Total Size <62480B> Used <628B> Still allocated <0B>
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- START OF WINDOW LOAD
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:126: ----- PERSIST TOTAL NOT FOUND, SETTING: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:135: ----- PERSIST TARGETS NOT FOUND, SETTING: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:138: ----- PERSIST END, TOTAL IS CURRENTLY: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:139: ----- PERSIST END, TARGETS IS CURRENTLY: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- END OF WINDOW LOAD
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- END OF INIT
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:213: Done initializing, pushed window: 0x20020c0c
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 1
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UP PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 1
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 2
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UP PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 2
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 3
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UP PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 3
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UP PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 1
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 1
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 1
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 1
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 1
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 8
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 2
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 8
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 2
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 8
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 2
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 8
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 2
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 8
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 2
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 12
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 3
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 12
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 3
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 12
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 3
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 12
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 3
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 12
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 3
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 16
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 4
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 16
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 4
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 16
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 4
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 16
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 4
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 16
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 4
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 20
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 5
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 20
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 5
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 20
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 5
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 20
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 5
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 20
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 5
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER SELECT PRESSED
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER PERSIST VALUES
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- END OF WINDOW UNLOAD
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 4
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 24
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] ocess_manager.c:419: Heap Usage for App <ScoreTrack: Total Size <62480B> Used <628B> Still allocated <0B>
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- START OF WINDOW LOAD
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:138: ----- PERSIST END, TOTAL IS CURRENTLY: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:139: ----- PERSIST END, TARGETS IS CURRENTLY: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- UPDATE TOTAL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE TARGETS
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE SCORE
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- AFTER UPDATE ALL
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- END OF WINDOW LOAD
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[INFO] button_click.c:19: ----- END OF INIT
[DEBUG] button_click.c:20: ----- SCORE: 0
[DEBUG] button_click.c:21: ----- TOTAL: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:22: ----- TARGETS: 6
[DEBUG] button_click.c:213: Done initializing, pushed window: 0x20020c0c
```

I tried to use data structures instead for saving and retrieving these values but cannot for the life of me figure out how this is done. The example on the Pebble dev site isn't padded out enough for me to fill in the blanks. Still only a hobby coder for things like this so there are probably a whole bunch of basics that I'm just completely missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I misinterpreted the key value as just the integer that you want to save to the storage, and not an actual key value for the place where the value lives in storage. So every time I saved and retrieved the values it was saving and retrieving from different locations depending on what the value was at the time.

Looking at the Persist Counter code example at the following page helped me
https://developer.pebble.com/examples/

Relevant code is now

```
#define NUM_TOTAL_DEFAULT 0
#define NUM_TARGETS_DEFAULT 0
#define NUM_TOTAL_PKEY 1
#define NUM_TARGETS_PKEY 2

...

static void persistValues() {
  persist_write_int(NUM_TARGETS_PKEY, targets);
  persist_write_int(NUM_TOTAL_PKEY, total);
}

... 

static void init(void) {
  // SET PERSISTENT VALUES IF EXISTS
  total = persist_exists(NUM_TOTAL_PKEY) ? persist_read_int(NUM_TOTAL_PKEY) : NUM_TOTAL_DEFAULT;
  targets = persist_exists(NUM_TARGETS_PKEY) ? persist_read_int(NUM_TARGETS_PKEY) : NUM_TARGETS_DEFAULT;

...

}

static void deinit(void) {
  // SAVE VALUES IN TO PERSISTENT STORAGE
  persistValues();

  window_destroy(window);
}
```